# Search object key name and use function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an object which I am trying to push in an array

```
$scope.xslLetterSpacing = {
                            "_name": "letter-spacing",
                            "__prefix": "xsl",
                            "__text": "2pt"
                          };
```

So above the object which I am trying to push in another array:-

```
$scope.frontObjct = {
"stylesheet": {
    "attribute-set": [{
            "attribute": {
                "_name": "text-align",
                "__prefix": "xsl"
            },
            "_name": "__frontmatter",
            "__prefix": "xsl"
        },
        {
            "attribute": [{
                    "_name": "space-before",
                    "__prefix": "xsl"
                },
                {
                    "_name": "space-before.conditionality",
                    "__prefix": "xsl",
                    "__text": "retain"
                },
                {
                    "_name": "font-size",
                    "__prefix": "xsl",
                    "__text": "16pt"
                },
                {
                    "_name": "font-weight",
                    "__prefix": "xsl",
                    "__text": "500"
                },
                {
                    "_name": "line-height",
                    "__prefix": "xsl",
                    "__text": "90%"
                }
            ],
            "_name": "__frontmatter__title",
            "_use-attribute-sets": "common.title",
            "__prefix": "xsl"
        }
    ],
    "_xmlns:xsl": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform",
    "_xmlns:fo": "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format",
    "_version": "2.0",
    "__prefix": "xsl"
}
```

}

So now what I am trying to do is to put condition. When `_name": "letter-spacing"` is **not** found in the `attribute-set[1]` , then push the `xslLetterSpacing` object in the attribute array and if the data object with `_name": "letter-spacing"` is already there in the `Obj` then do nothing.

I tried this to do with it is getting repeated with number of object already present in the array.

```
angular.forEach($scope.frontObjct.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute , function(value, key) {
                    if (key !== "_name") {
                    //pushing extra data to attribute field
                        $timeout(function(){
                          $scope.frontObjct.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute.push($scope.xslLetterSpacing);
                            console.log($scope.frontObjct );
                        },500);
                    }
                });
```

*Where am I going wrong ?*

Comment: 'attribute' is an array, don't you need to iterate through the array and test each object in the array?

Comment: @SPlatten Yes I need to match each and every object's `_name` in the array  but I am not getting how.

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. Those are javascript objects, JSON is a string notation

Comment: @Liam I am pretty sure those JSON are defined in javascript objects. Isn't it ?

Comment: No your wrong, JSON is a **string** i.e. `"{\"a\":\"test\"}"` a Javascript object is an object, i.e. `{a:"test"}`

Comment: @Liam So this is not the correct way to define JSON in angular ? Regardless , I am yet clueless with the solution of my question.

Comment: I repeat, there is no JSON in this question...

Comment: @Liam Fine, thanks . I got the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var itemLetterSpacing = $scope.Obj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute.filter(function(item) {
      return item._name === "letter-spacing";
})[0];

if(!itemLetterSpacing) { 
     $scope.Obj.stylesheet["attribute-set"][1].attribute.push($scope.xslLetterSpacing);
}
console.log($scope.Obj);
```

Comment: I am getting error `angular.js:13424 Error: [ng:areq] Argument controller is not a function`

Comment: copy now and  try

Comment: Thanks , This is exactly I was looking for.